# How to transfer data automatically from one MySQL Database to another MySQL Database?

Tags: mysql, dts, data-transfer

I have two MySQL Database which are in different machines.
I want to transfer data from one Server to another automatically.
Lets say, I want my data transfer to happen each day morning 4:00.

Can it be done? Is there any MySQL built in feature by which we can do it?

I want to transfer data from some specific tables not from the whole DB.

Comment: in PHPMyAdmin version there is an option Synchronize which does the same job, so it's possible :) but dont know how :(

Comment: But can it be done automatically by MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want automated solution handled by MySQL, then it's replication what you need. Since the topic is broad and covered in detail in MySQL manual, I suggest you sit down and read what [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html) says on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

mysqldump -uuser -ppass your_db your_table1 > to_sql

and then use crontab run

mysql -uroot -ppass -hhost < to_sql

Comment: I am not supposed to do it manually. I want an automatic approach where it can be scheduled.

Comment: @Deviprasad Das how about mysql's replication? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Comment: I think it can't start automatically :(